# Community Project Highlights 2014

Tags: discussion

Welcome to the first Community Project Highlights! Here's what it's all about:

As a member, you can post an answer to this question with details about a personal project (preferably an ongoing project, since one of the points of this is for you to regularly update your answer with extra details, as your project progresses). You can have multiple answers (thus multiple projects) posted. Said projects should be gamedev related: games, game engines and game libraries are great examples of projects that are on the topic.

It is recommended for everyone to upvote the projects which seem interesting to them. That's because at the end of the year, the most voted project will be declared the most popular and will receive a prize.

This question will be edited as the event progresses. Some things to keep in mind:

1. Even though you can have multiple answers posted, please don't abuse this permission. Post your most relevant projects only.
2. You may embed pictures of your projects, but again, don't abuse this permission. Keep the picture count within decent limits. Remember: you can always link to external pictures, if you feel like adding extra stuff.

Comment: Great idea. Let's see some more answers.

Comment: Was this project discontinued, or do you still plan to declare a winner and hand out a prize?

Comment: @rdb I contacted a moderator about this. Hopefully we still have a prize around here :D

Answer (score 19):

For the last year I've focused on creating realistic graphics for my game, mostly for outdoor scenes. Here are some results, running in realtime with Panda3D:

I have also done a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmbUQWlJVI0).

[image]
[image]

You can find further information here: http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17050 and here: http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16441

Comment: This looks awesome, especially the snowy landscape. How's the performance?

Comment: Thanks! The terrain runs at 500fps, when enabling vegetation I get 200fps on my Gtx 670. The sponza scene uses global illumination and therefore runs at 16ms, but when I optimized it it should be arround 8-9ms, so 120fps :)

Comment: wow this is beautiful.

Comment: The snowy terrain is stunning! Very impressive, well done.

Answer (score 15):

### Asteroid Outpost

A 2D, tower-strategy game developed in XNA with a web-UI.

[image]

Build solar stations for power, laser miners for minerals, and towers to defend yourself! Power must be transmitted from the power stations to where it is needed through power lines. Keep your laser miners supplied with power, and they will extract a steady stream of minerals from the asteroids that you can use to aid in the construction of various defensive mechanisms. Fend off the alien armada to keep your people safe.

Check out the [progression of the game on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F3a8.jpg), follow [my dev blog](http://jcpmcdonald.com/), or [read some tweets](https://twitter.com/AsteroidOutpost).

The engine is my own, even though sometimes I wish it wasn't. It has a component-based system that uses JSON to store all the entity information, and very similar JSON to tell the web-UI what's going on. Written in XNA (C#) with a web front end using [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), and of course: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This is on the order of 400 commits, and 25k lines of code over the course of many years on and off.

---

**UPDATE**

I have chosen to abandon Asteroid Outpost due its massive scale. Asteroid Outpost started as an open source project, and will be again, I will be pushing the latest code back up to Bitbucket. As is tradition, I will also be writing up a full postmortem when I get a chance. It has been fun, but I want smaller projects.

Comment: Sad to hear that you're abandoning this, but good on you for opening it up! It would be good to see any design documents and/or concepts, as this would tremendously help anyone possibly picking this up. Looking forward to the post-mortem.

Answer (score 15):

## Tallowmere

2D action roguelike platformer being created with Unity for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

[image: Tallowmere screenshot]

Tallowmere features randomly-generated rooms, weapons that give your hero unique abilities, enemies with different attacks you must block with your shield, traps you should avoid. Special room types, bosses, potions, stats, passive abilities, dialogue, cutscenes, infinite jumping, dev console, high-score system, permadeath, and lots of blood and gibbing.

I've just started coding and creating different outfits, hats, and shields, then I'll be working on local shared-screen co-op, followed by network co-op, and then more monsters, weapons, story elements, bosses, and room types!

All the code is in Unity's JavaScript language, over 18,000 lines last I checked. Sprites and particles are my own, sound effects created with [Bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net), music created with [Figure](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/figure/).

[Homepage](http://www.tallowmere.com/) • [IndieDB](http://www.indiedb.com/games/tallowmere) • [Personal Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChrisNZL) • [Official Twitter](https://twitter.com/Tallowmere) • [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/Tallowmere) • [Infrequent dev blog](https://medium.com/@chrisnzl)

Comment: This is fun. Play it.

Comment: And now it's on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/app/340520/

Answer (score 10):

### [Age of Goblins: New Korbly](http://www.indiedb.com/games/age-of-goblins-new-korbly) ([Demo](http://ageofgoblins.com/newkorbly/Web.html))

It's my first project using Unity3D. It's a top down space game (3D rendered on a 2D plane of play). Players can build their own ships by snapping components together. For example, adding a bridge component and putting control thrusters on either side is enough to complete a small ship. Player space stations can be built in the same way. Ship and station components can be salvaged by trade, construction from raw materials or salvage (of existing wrecks or ones the player creates). It supports multiplayer as well. [Seth](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19126/seth-battin) assisted with development as well.

[image]

It's currently on hold while I finish a writing job. I'll post more updates for it when I get back to working on it in about a month.

Comment: Namedroped.  I touched the code, but just barely.

Comment: Telling me where my code is bad is pretty much like writing the new code yourself. Also, evidence of teamwork: http://i.imgur.com/F3AlOmy.png

Comment: Oh yeah, I almost forgot.  I also starred as the clubbed seal in this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aI2plAXIrXk

Comment: Ah yes, the multiplayer testing. I figured out how to make that much smoother too. We shall battle again in the future.

Answer (score 10):

[image: 1st Logo]

### Get that laptop, DDOS your enemies, Hack the Gibson!

### Pants are Required!

---

### The Team:

The group behind the Malware Tycoon is called the “Game Dev Minor League.” We are composed of 5 members, @hasherr, @Grey, @joapet99, @ChristainCareaga, and myself, Pip. GDML was founded my hasherr, Grey, and I on March 25, 2014, and have progressed since then, inviting new members as long as they meet the requirements: they must be friendly, have frequented the chat, and must be under 18 years old – the “minor” portion of our name. Currently, all members are active, and have contributed. Christain serves as our support, as he has even more experience than I do with our tools.

---

### Target Platforms:

Malware Tycoon is targeted for Windows 7/8, Ubuntu, and Mac OSX, if possible.
Note: It may eventually be operable on other operating systems, if all of our features can be proved compatible.

---

### Programming Language:

Python (version 3.4)

### Libraries:

Pygame (version 1.9.2)

---

### Description:

Malware Tycoon is heavily inspired by [Game Dev Tycoon](http://www.greenheartgames.com/app/game-dev-tycoon/), an indie title created by Greenheart Games. You play as a wannabe hacker, and learn how to create and use more and more malware, as the game progresses. You can either take on jobs from a corporation, secretly, or go out on your own, and try to live as a lone wolf. Eventually, a semi-realistic history will be implemented, including major Windows operations systems/versions, different Apple computers, and possibly the use of several different Linux distros.

Comment: Awesome :) I'd like to see a demo by the end of the year. Good luck!

Comment: I want to try it, too.  Post a build.  Or a link to the read-only repo.

Comment: @SethBattin We havn't discussed the releasing of the builds yet, but we will post one as soon as we can all agree that it is good enough, and playable.

Comment: @AlexM. I will be sure to notify you also when a demo is released :)

Comment: Great Idea @Pip !

Comment: Nice logo!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks @Jon! I don't know who made it, do you? :P

Answer (score 8):

## [Demoscene Pinball](http://demoscenepinball.dy.fi)

[image: Screenshot]

Demoscene Pinball is a 3D pinball simulator, which I have been working on as a hobby for the past three years slowly but regularly.

It is now finally completed and can be downloaded from http://demoscenepinball.dy.fi/. This game is also my submission to [Assembly 2014 Game development competition](http://www.assembly.org/summer14/demoscene/gamedev).

### Gameplay features

- [Demoscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene) theme
- 5 special modes
- Multiball
- Skill shot
- Typical pinball elements such as bumpers, slingshots, kickbacks, 3 flippers, multiple ramps, rails, buttons ...
- Online highscores

### Technical information

- Written in Java 1.7 using OpenGL 3.3 self made renderer
- Uses [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) - The Lightweight Java Game Library
- Physics are created with [JBullet](http://jbullet.advel.cz/) - Java port of Bullet Physics Library
- Background music has been generated with [cgMusic](http://codeminion.com/blogs/maciek/2008/05/cgmusic-computers-create-music/)
- HDR rendering
- Sharp and glossy reflections

I am a programmer and I have created the game alone without any artists, designers or musicians. It has been challenging, but I have managed to create a visual style I'm proud of. The glossy metal shaders reflecting the playfield dynamically has greatly reduced the need for textures. 3D models are procedurally generated mostly by extruding 3D spline curves or Java 2D shapes.

Feel free to try the game and submit your scores to the highscore server. Windows users don't even need Java, as I have used [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) to compile a native Windows executable and installer. All feedback including bug reports are very welcome.

### Update:

Introduction video of the game is now [available for download](http://msell.kapsi.fi/pinball/Demoscene_Pinball_Intro.mp4) (30MB). There is also a [YouTube version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aItZq5gEX4o), but the framerate is quite poor.

### Update2:

I have created [Inside Demoscene Pinball](http://demoscenepinball.dy.fi/inside/), a separate web page explaining the technology behind the game. It gives a deeper insight to the different features of the game than what is observable by just playing it.

Comment: Congrats on [4th place](http://archive.assembly.org/2014/gamedev/demoscene-pinball-by-itchi-lonely-coders)!

Answer (score 7):

### nIce Suite

Well I enjoy algorithms and math more than the creative aspect of making games, so I decided to make a game engine instead. After 3 months of development (in a 5 month timespan, because school and work get in the way) the engine is functional in a bare bones kind of way. So before I go any farther I've decided to make a few small games like Solitaire and Minesweeper, just to make sure my design is on the right track.

[image: nIce Suite main menu]

I'm not very far in development yet, but since the engine is ECS based, and scripts are just a component that can be added to anything, it makes it real easy to add fancy transition effects. For example (3 MB gif): [http://i.imgur.com/TEryoW8.gif](https://i.imgur.com/TEryoW8.gif)

Also, because I'm a college student just trying to challenge myself, I have no plans to make any money with this project and everything is open source, even if that source is horribly uncommented with no real documentation (yet). Everything is in C# (the One True Language) with the OpenTK library, and most of it should be readable without comments, or so I tried to design it.

Engine source: [GitHub](https://github.com/IcyDefiance/nIce-Game)

Suite source: [GitHub](https://github.com/IcyDefiance/nIce-Suite)

Windows binaries: [IcyDev](http://www.icydev.net/nicesuite/publish.htm) (My website)

Comment: At long last. A C# user! Rejoice brother!

Answer (score 7):

## [C-Dogs SDL](http://cxong.github.io/cdogs-sdl/)

Overhead run-and-gun with 2-4 local multiplayer, campaigns and deathmatches.

[image]

**Available for Windows, OS X, Linux, Android and GCW-Zero**

**Github:** https://github.com/cxong/cdogs-sdl

C-Dogs SDL is an open source port of a classic DOS game, [C-Dogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-Dogs). It was a pretty decent overhead run-and-gun back in the day. For about a year now I've been hacking away at it, picking up the project from abandonment and implementing new features such as:

- Quick play game mode
- Static maps and map editor
- 4-player co-op
- Co-op AI

But the bigger gain for me I think is the learning experiences this has provided. Refactoring C code with a 20-year-old legacy was quite an experience! My long term plan is to leave this project in a good state, having implemented network multiplayer (everyone asks for that) and replacing the freeware graphics so it's 100% FLOSS.

As with all open source projects, **contributions welcome!** Play the game, send me feedback, share your ideas, patches etc.

- Update Aug 2014: a port for GCW-Zero was made!

  [image: GCW-Zero photo]

Comment: C-Dogs was my favorite game on my old Win95 machine. Forking this ASAP.

Answer (score 7):

### Necromonster!

---

Necromonster is a 2D, topdown RPG. You can read all about the story and game mechanic in Readme of the [Github Repo!](https://github.com/linkey11/Necromonster)

[image: Necro Screenshot]

**Language:** Python (2.7)

**Required Libs:** Pygame, NumPy(for path-finding)

**Game Mechanic:**

Pretty much the main game mechanic is that you control a monster which goes into dungeons and gets loot for you. There are 2 xp bars, the fast filling monster bar, and slow filling wizard bar. The monster levels like you'd expect, but when it dies, it's a permadeath. The wizard goes on to summon more monsters, who bring back loot from dungeons that make him stronger. Instead of getting classic pre-made weapons and armor in dungeons, you get material(s) for creating new weapons, tools, and armor. These materials can then be used to create new items at a blacksmith. Tools will also be enchantable to give them interesting, unique, and special effect(s).

**Features (so far):**

- Basic Player movement, maploading, enemies, etc.
- Inventory (small pop-up window in the corner)
- Shadows (for buildings) and Day/Night cycle
- NPC's
- Takeover (when monsters are killed it is possible to take there shape)
- Weapon System (currently being worked on)

If you don't have python, here is the [100th commit build](https://github.com/linkey11/Necromonster/releases/tag/v0.1-dev). It is 15 commits behind and a good amount has been added in those 15 commits.

Comment: Is this meant to be open source or you're just hosting on Github? There's no license.

Comment: Normal US copyright laws apply.

Comment: Are you guys still using any of my art? I am not offended either way :P

Comment: @Pip most of our current art is placeholder art, we are in need of an artist though!

Comment: Haven't tried your game yet but from your readme your gameplay has an interesting twist - you should include it here!

Comment: I didn't want to repeat it in 2 places but why not! Thanks @congusbongus

Comment: Noice. concept sounds super interesting. BTW, mind if I ask you how you are doing the shadow for the two buildings?

Answer (score 7):

## Battery

### [image]

It's a game I just work on occasionally. There used to be page where I've posted project updates (and some of the algorithms) occasionally. But it's been a long time since my last update. It's basically a 2.5D top-down chasing game, in which you, as circle-shaped robot should run from your hunters, and try to catch your target. So far I've implemented some basic functionalities, such as basic rendering, simple AI, maze generation and local-network communication.

The game is going to feature Online play (up to 64 players in same game), match making, single player (with AI), and if everything goes right, there will be other game modes.

It's not going to be an opensource project, but I might use your suggestions on every aspect of the game.

---

**Platform:** Windows (xp or higher), Linux, iPhone, android, ...

I just hate macOSx but I might also add support for it. Also I might consider windows phone, specially if someday MS decides to add OpenGL support.

---

**Language:** C++

**Engine:** currently working with [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org), but there is an old (working version) of the game written with [Esenthel Engine](http://esenthel.com). For the prototype my friend used [Game Maker](https://www.yoyogames.com/studio). And for a short period of time, I tried developing it on top of [cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.com).

---

**Playable Demos:** you can find multiple playable demoes in my [one drive folder](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ED39467E732B4F81!200&authkey=!AJK4VmVoD464BOU&ithint=folder). while each has it's own unique set of features!

- For testing the game as in the above screenshot, check version 0.0.4
- For getting an idea how the game will look like in the end check the prototype version.
- For testing inputs on mobile devices you can test those apk files, and give me some feedback which one you liked the best.

Comment: This looks awesome compared to the initial prototype. Keep it up!

Comment: @SpartanDonut the thing it's moving way too slow

Answer (score 6):

## CraftPlatform

[image: A screenshot form the current version]

You have played minecraft, right? You might also have tried some mods for it. The thing is, the modding community is huge even though it's nightmare to create any mods for minecraft. The purpose of this project is to build a platform for minecraft like games and mods. The "vanilla" release will be a mod itself, which can also be modded easily. I do not want to call this a minecraft clone, but a mod platform that can be used to create minecraft clones.

**Current planned features**:

- Highly optimized voxel cube rendering engine
- Nice lighting and shadows with deferred shading engine
- Full API available to add and modify anything in the game world
- Store multiple worlds separate from each other
- Client-server approach; single player mode will connect to a local server
- Mod based terrain generation

**Current features**:

- Generate a mesh from voxel data and render that with very simple shader
- Occlusion culling is now working
- Chunks are octrees trying to compress the block data if at all possible (If all node children are the same, mark the node solid and just store the block type the children were storing)
- Texturing and material information is sent to the GPU for each block

So what will be in the game without mods? Nothing! Even the basic cubes will be a mod. This enables the mods to do anything. Generate dungeons with final bosses, simulating dwarf fortress, flowing liquids, playing god(s), shoot rockets in space, build space stations. You name it. The world is designed to be seemingly infinite, which is 2147483648 chunks of blocks in every direction. That will take [363913989089 times the age of current universe](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14750234#14750234) to visit every chunk. And then you can have more worlds if you run out the first one. ;)

This project is in it's very early stage, so nothing to show yet other than the screenshot above. Also, planned features list will most likely grow as I get more ideas during the development. I have also not yet decided if I'm going to release it open source, but I am not excluding that possibility yet. Time will tell.

### Techs used

C#, .net/mono, OpenTK

Answer (score 5):

It would too tough to pick an incomplete project.  Here's a silly one that I actually finished.  (The image is a link.)

[image: http://itsobviously.com/nmaze/]

The key inputs work.  This surprised my front-end dev fellows; they said they don't associate correct key event binding with terrible styling.

Hit the random button to get an idea of how the url parameters work.  If you want to reduce the number of dimensions, just leave out some of the numbers.

The last number is the random seed, so the same url will generate the same maze.

Hovering shows connected rooms, in case you can't divine the passageways from my "graphics".

The engine (lol) supports any number of dimensions, but the display is limited to only utilize 4 of them.  Previously, I was simply wrapping more and more tables around themselves, but control schemes and visual depictions became a problem.  Also it turns out that 4 dimensions is utterly impossible anyway, so 5 and 6 really aren't needed.

Comment: For a more traditional maze, try: http://itsobviously.com/nmaze/?-100-100-10615 (you may need to zoom out your browser window.

Comment: based on how you show those mazes, I think it's better if you change Q/A shortcuts to A/D.

Comment: @Ali.S You know, that's a pretty good idea; it would allow easy two-handed play.  The current scheme is a relic of when E/D, R/F, etc., were also pairs.

Answer (score 5):

### [Mentality](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ecpxooknihtiygd/FugYANZfR-)

[image]

So I absolutely love Magic: the Gathering and similar games like Hearthstone, and have always wanted to create a digital CCG myself. Now that I have acquired enough skills to actually make games, I can finally do that! This is my first large project, after lots of practice with smaller projects.

It's currently very simple and has a terrible interface, but it's still *kinda* fun to play if you can figure it out. Improvements are on the way! :)

Techs used: [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) (using C#), [OpenGUI](https://github.com/mrzapp/opengui)

**Warning: the game is currently kind of really boring. Will be fixed soon(ish).**

Comment: This sounds absolutely fantastic. Me, as well, wanted to make something like; my own digital card game. Good luck with this project. :D

Comment: @Tofu_Craving_Redish_BlueDragon I'm glad to hear that! I'll update this post as the game is improved, though the next update may take a while. The code has become a huge mess, so I'm cleaning that up first. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Tarbeyon

### The Developer:

Hello all! I am a progressing programmer from the United States. Currently, I am spending time on several projects, including a team voxel engine, using C# and SharpDX, and a trading game called *Envio*, using C# and Monogame, as well as this one.

### Target Platforms:

Tarbeyon is targeted to be playable on Windows (7, 8, 8.1, and possibly others), Linux distros (mainly Ubuntu), and Mac OSX. Other operating systems may work, but don't count on it. As the game is currently being ported to C#, I have no idea which platforms will support it, but this will be updated.

### Programming Language:

Tarbeyon is written in the Python 3.x branch of the Python programming language. It uses the Pygame library for graphics and other functionality.

### Description:

Tarbeyon is heavily inspired by Terraria and similar games, but is not currently planned to be a sandbox game, although that may change later. It is in a very early stage, mainly because I had to constantly deal with performance issues, so I do not have much time to create new features. Also, Tarbeyon is only an occasional project, and my other game takes priority over it, usually.

### Images

#### Warning...... all art is placeholder and a bit messy!

[image: Gameplay Screenshot]

### Downloads:

If you want to try Tarbeyon, you can find it and the (Windows) dependencies here:

https://bitbucket.org/flaminghatgames/tarbeyon/downloads

The dependencies for other platforms should be fairly easy to find ([Python here](http://python.org), and [Pygame here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame)).

To run, first install the dependencies, then unzip the zip file. After that, run `Main.py`.

Note: When I can figure out how to create an installer that works, I will post either an installer for an exe or just an exe.

Comment: Are you Benjamin Ward, if not what's your relation to him? Seems weird to refer to yourself in the third person otherwise

Comment: It is sort of odd to refer to myself in third person, but..... meh. I mostly copied the git repo's README file, and threw this together @congusbongus. This post will get a rework soon.

Answer (score 3):

### [Kotlin_ThreeJS](https://bitbucket.org/ClassicThunder/kotlin_threejs/src/bcc4d5725528?at=master)

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/ClassicThunder/kotlin_threejs/src/bcc4d5725528?at=master)

I got bored of C#/XNA so I have been looking for a new stack to play with. I really like JetBrains new language [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) which targets both the JVM and JavaScript so I decided it would be fun to learn the language and ThreeJS by creating an interop layer.

Current only the getting started and [Random Particle](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_particles_random.html) example are working.

Answer (score 2):

### SquareMaze

[image: SquareMaze]

<sub>Click the image for an older beta test play through by my boss!</sub>

SquareMaze is an app made to test your reactions and see how well you can cope in a fast paced scenario. You control a little red square around a randomly generated maze and earn as many points as you can, but it's a little more complicated than that.

This was my first game *ever*. I had a fun time making it, and getting a brief introduction to the industry. It's a simple side scroll-er, if you get far enough;), made for android, and soon to be ported to other platforms.

## Language/Libraries

C#/Unity

## Platform

Mobile, at the moment only android.

## Release

This game should be release on the Play store soon, and I'll post the link when it happens. <sub>Sorry in advance for the ads:(</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**KaM Remake**

[image]

The KaM Remake mod is an attempt to reinvigorate the original “Knights and Merchants: The Shattered Kingdom” strategy game. Our goals are to make it work on today’s computers and operating systems, implement a fully featured online multiplayer system, as well as to fix the many bugs in the game engine. To do this we have started from scratch, writing our own code for the game engine but still relying on many original resource files. We assume that you own the original KaM game, (the installer checks for it) otherwise you should buy it – it’s available in a number of online gaming stores.
The KaM Remake executable is freeware and is built by enthusiasts. Applications used: Delphi 6, Delphi 7, FastMM4, Lazarus, OpenGL, OpenAL, zLib, PNGImage, MadExcept, libZPlay.

Comment: Beautiful! Good luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nemesis Sidekick](https://github.com/angarg12/nemesis-sidekick)

Nemesis Sidekick is a two players, offline, vertical scroller space shooter game. Players control two playable characters, Hero and Sidekick.

The game features two play modes, Nemesis and Sidekick.

Nemesis is a competitive play mode. On this mode, only one player can be the winner of a game. The aim is to complete the objectives of each level and be the last player alive.

Sidekick is a cooperative play mode. On this mode, either both players win or lose a game. The aim is to complete the objectives of each level with both players alive.
The project

The game also features a faction system. Hero is blue, while Sidekick is red. Players can only hard or be harmed by enemies of the opposite color. Purple enemies however are able to damage both players.

Nemesis Sidekick is an open source game made with the Unity Engine in C#. The game code is under a GPLv3 license, and all its assets are under a CC BY-SA license unless explicitly stated otherwise.

[image: In level screen]

A small gallery can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akd3n.png).

### On a personal level

I have always wanted to do my own videogame. Is just a personal challenge. After trying out tutorials, tools, books etc. I felt that I was just pushing the act of making a game further and further away, so finally one day I got down to it and started coding a game. Sure, its far from perfect, but at least is my own.

### On a game design level

I have quite a few ideas for videogames in my head, but this one seems not to be overly ambitious and fit for an opera prima. The specific idea for this game came to my mind one day sitting in a friend house. We were discussing how hard is to find offline cooperative games, where you can just physically sit in the same room as your friends and play together. The I had an idea, what about a game that must be played two players, and where being physically close to each other played a part in the gameplay?.

Little by little this idea took shape in the form of Nemesis Sidekick, and I expanded it a little bit with other interesting gameplay concepts.

First the game is two players only, and both players play in the same keyboard. This forces players to be very close to each other, and this has some implications. As the game was conceived as competitive in nature, I pictured players harassing and messing with each other in order to get an advantage in the game.

In order to make the experience more interesting, I decided to add a second, cooperative game mode, where I could experiment with other mechanics.

In the current iteration, the competitive mode (Nemesis) requires one player to eliminate the other and beat the level (right now only points are counted) to be the winner. The little twist is that when a player dies, he gets a speed and power buff. That means that every time your enemy becomes more and more dangerous, and sort of balances the game.

The cooperative mode (Sidekick) requires both players to survive and beat the level together. The twist here is that friendly fire is enabled, and the death buff is applied to the other player when one dies. So, in the one hand you want your partner to survive in order to beat the level, but on the other you would like that sweet sweet buff.

### Current state and future plans

The project has been stale for a month due to me changing jobs, country and not having internet at home. Hopefully I can get back on the road again soon.

The game currently has mostly placeholder graphics and sound/music, and the levels and enemies are just testing prototypes. Also the game hasn't been playtested by anybody else than me, so I didn't had any feedback about the game system. Right now I am more concerned about learning how to make games, and my aim is to put in place some basic system that can be extended to produce a complete game. Of course I am open for anybody who wants to contribute, collaborations are always welcome!.